# Turtlebot depth image not displaying with Image_view with gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, kinect, turtlebot, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I'm using the turtlebot_simulator package to simulate in gazebo.

Ubuntu 13.04 - 32bit

Ros Hydro

Turtlebot-apps v2.2.0

Gazebo v1.9

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

Using the image_view on the depth image returns a blank gray window. Where as using the same command on the RGB stream works perfectly. Here's a screen shot of whats happening so save myself trying to explain it.

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/J0d354T.png)

Any ideas why this would occur? The depth data is displayed correctly in rviz.

---

```
Rostopic Hz /camera/depth/image_raw
subscribed to [/camera/depth/image_raw]
average rate: 2.609
    min: 0.360s max: 0.420s std dev: 0.02625s window: 4
average rate: 2.765
    min: 0.330s max: 0.420s std dev: 0.03023s window: 7
average rate: 2.769
    min: 0.330s max: 0.420s std dev: 0.02514s window: 10
```

and

```
Rostopic info /camera/depth/image_raw
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://Thesis-4740111:57881/)

Subscribers: None
```

---

After running those commands, the image_view started working on the depth. I guess magic will explain it.

Something must have changed over the last few days.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80946/turtlebot-depth-image-not-displaying-with-image_view-with-gazebo/) by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-18**:
Can you show the output of rostopic hz and info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just started working again for no obvious reason.

---

Originally posted by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) with karma: 103 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arronlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/5223/arronlee/) on 2013-10-20**:
Thanksfor your info. But using code to deal with the image probelm is too complicated for me. I am learn to create [web image viewer](http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/how-to-create-web-viewer.shtml) and [windows image viewer](http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/how-to-create-windows-viewer.shtml) using some manual tools which can be customized by users to help me with the image displaying program. Any good suggestion? Thanks in adcance.

**Comment by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on 2014-03-01**:
Any hints on how you solved it? I cant see depth/image_raw nor depth_registered/image_raw using image_view. However, depth_registered/image_raw is shown in Rviz but I can't save images directly from there. Depth_image_raw is not publishing (checked with rostopic hz).

**Comment by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on 2014-03-01**:
Just realised you use simulator. New question, http://answers.ros.org/question/134686/turtlebot-depth-image-not-showing-in-image_view/